# I want to use DAO's but how do I inject the returned objects dependencies cleanly

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, dao

Ok so I have my dependency injection container and a DAO that I use like this to get an order for example:

```
$container = new DIContainer();
$orderDAO = $container->get('orderDAO');
$order = $orderDAO->fetchById($someId);
```

and then I have my order object which is easy to use.

The thing is what if my `$order` object has dependencies on a `Logger`, `Config` and one or two more objects like that, since my `$orderDAO` instantiates the object wouldn't it have to have access to or be able to create those additional objects and I am pretty sure the `$orderDAO` object should definitely not know anything about those additional objects, especially not know how to create them.

I know I could inject the dependency injection container into the DAO when it is being instantiated (from within the DIC) and that way I would have access to any dependency my objects have from within the DAO but something about doing it that way doesn't feel right to me for some reason and I definitely don't want to be doing static calls all over the place either so that method is out the window.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you won't change to a J2EE environment? :) But that's interesting. I selfish coded a framework for this. (years ago) Without event knowing about the word 'DAO'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow DI container to manage internal object dependencies, like assigning Logger, Config and stuff like that inside the object you instantiating - is the normal way to do the things. If for some reason you don't want to allow DI container to do that, then you could just create default constructor and assigning this values in it.

Actually it's looks like you need to put inside some infrastructural things, things in that way it's better to do that as simple as possible without some additional things, because it will get you to the unnecessary complexity.

---

**UPD:**

So productDAO does not have access to Config, etc... But you want that product have that. I think it's pretty wrong from the design point of view. Because normally entities which main goal is store the data shouldn't have any functions except their business logic. if you wan't to do logging and configuration - you should do it inside DAO, but not in product. But anyway, if want, then just create wrapper for the things which could be changed in future (let's say Logger) and then simply assign this value in constructor by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and what do you mean "put inside some infastructural" things?

Comment: For me logging, config etc... anything which do not connected with business logic - is some parts of your project infrastructure. And I cal it infrastructural stuff)

Comment: Ok but can you give me an example of what you mean please because I am not sure I fully understand you.

Comment: Example of what? Managing dependency with DI container or creating constructor?

Comment: I know how to manage dependencies with a DI container the problem is when I use my a DAO like `$productDAO = $container->get('productDAO'); $product = $productDAO->fetchById($id);`. The productDAO creates a product object and populates its properties with data about that product from the database but what I want to know is how to I give that product object its dependencies since it is created in the productDAO and the productDAO does not have access to the Config and Logger objects etc